# Dev Manpages are not completed

Tags: c, manpage

I cannot get '`man aton`', '`man argp_parse`', etc, but I have '`man memcpy`', '`man 7 ip`' for example.  I've already installed `manpages-dev`.   What packages I still lost to get all the basic C function's manuals?

My ubuntu is 18.10.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just realized it's a typo. I should run '`man atol`' instead of '`man aton`', this works actually. But for the '`man argp_parse`', it's still not found.

Answer (score 0):

You will not get the manpage for `argp_parse` because of the fact that it is listed on [missing man-page since Ubuntu 12.04 LTS](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man7/missing.7.html).

Consider to subscribe to the related bug report [#349388 on Debian bug tracking system](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=349388) and/or file new bug on LaunchPad.